# angular.js:13642 Error: [$compile:multidir]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario where i need to change the star colors based on hover value 
for appending the color i am using custom directive and for displaying stars i am using ui-rating(ui-bootstrap)

html:

```
<uib-rating ng-model="rate" class="col-xs-3 star-color" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="rating=value;hoveringOver(value)" star-color rating="rating" ng-click="viewPage||fnPutRating(rating)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
```

here `star-color` is the custom directive

directive:

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.directive('starColor', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            rating: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log($scope.rating);
            switch (todoText) {
                case "1":
                    elem.style.color='red'
                    break;
                case "2":
                    elem.style.color='red'
                    break;
                case "3":
                    elem.style.color='green'
                    break;
                case "4":
                   elem.style.color='green'
                    break;
                case "5":
                    elem.style.color='green'
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

but here i am getting an error as

```
angular.js:13642 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [starColor (module: hrPortalApp), uibRating (module: ui.bootstrap.rating)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <span ng-mouseleave="reset()" ng-keydown="onKeydown($event)" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="{{range.length}}" aria-valuenow="{{value}}" aria-valuetext="{{title}}" ng-model="rate" class="col-xs-3 star-color" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="rating=value;hoveringOver(value)" star-color="" rating="rating" ng-click="viewPage||fnPutRating(rating)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating">
```

I dont understand why i am getting this error 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have multiple directives (in this case, `uibRating` and `starColor`) asking for a new scope on the same element.

One easy fix would be to parse `rating` inside the link function: use `$parse(attr.rating)(scope)` in your link function.

Comment: Thanks for answering;but i need to watch on the rating value if it changes then i need to append the color according to that

But when doing $parse(attr.rating) i am getting "rating" by which i am unable to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Two directives(uib-rating and star-color) requesting isolated scope on the same element is causing the problem.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.js - source code of uib-rating directive

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir - angularjs